# EclipseLink JPQL CASE Statetment returns NoResultException

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I would like to do a check in my PostgreSQL database with Eclipse Link in a named query and return a boolean. However when I change my count statement (which returns a correct value) to a case statement I get a NoResultException. What is the problem?

Following a simplified example:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.isExistent", 
  query = "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(u) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END 
           FROM User u WHERE u.someField = :someField")
```

Usage

```
    TypedQuery<Boolean> query = em.createNamedQuery("User.isExistent", Boolean.class);
    query.setParameter("someField", "someFieldValue");
    Boolean result = query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Turn on logging and see the SQL that is generated.  Try comparing it to your count query to see what might be going different.  You might also try getting a list instead of using getSingleResult() just in case you are hitting a known bug in EclipseLink with queries returning boolieans.  If it works, try the latest EclipseLink version.

Comment: I have the same problem using query.getResultList(), list is empty.

Comment: Sorry, i was mistaken on the workaround.  Bug is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340089 and says it is fixed in EL 2.2.0

Comment: Hmm. I use EL 2.5.2. For now I return the count and then I convert it to a boolean.